# PyCharm does not start gunicorn via WSL after the update

Tags: python, pycharm, gunicorn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm on version 2022.2.2 stopped running gunicorn via WSL in the configuration shown on the screenshot. Everything worked before that. If you run it from the console, everything starts calmly and also works properly on another computer.

The error:

> home/dmitry/.local/share/virtualenvs/helper_trpg-EK2L-CnU/bin/python3.10: unable to open file '/home/dmitry/projects/helper_trpg/\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\dmitry\.local\share\virtualenvs\helper_trpg-EK2L-CnU\bin\gunicorn': [Error 2] There is no such file or directory

Looks like the IDE adds the working directory path to the script path... How to fix this?

System:

- Windows 11 Pro 21H2
- WSL Ubuntu 20.04
- PyCharm Professional 2022.2.2

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this? I just hit this issue in PyCharm 2023.2. I thought I could finally not have to run a VM to work on an API on my Windows machine.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56434 here is the solution